# Is there any difference between Mac Safari and Windows Safari apart from UI/UX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, macos, safari, controller

currently I'm testing my website in which I'm getting a validation error message which should not come ideally.

The same things works fine in Windows Safari, but it fails in Mac Safari. Is there any difference in both the browser on how they handle Javascript and Ajax calls?

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in terms of interaction with the core systems - but the display and rendering of HTML, CSS and JS are identical as they use the same engine, WebKit. To read more about WebKit check this wikipedia article.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit

It may be some sort of caching issue, I would suggest trying a private browsing session or clearing cache to test your JavaScript.

See also this question which talks about the rendering engine differences (of which there are none)
[Differences between Safari for Windows and Safari for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308305/differences-between-safari-for-windows-and-safari-for-mac?rq=1)